# After using custom url for admin panel, On error it redirects to the front end home page

Tags: magento2

I am creating new website and on exception rather than showing error message it is redirecting to the home page. 
Expected result:

[image]

but redirecting to home page.

Comment: It is clearly mention that website code must start with letter.

Comment: It is fairly unclear to us what your problem is *exactly*, but it may help to check the file in `app\etc\env.php`.  There should be an array-value on/near line 5 called `frontName`.  This value should match the one that you are trying to enter.